# How to run selenium-cucumber eclipse project through command prompt

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, cucumber, eclipse

I need to run selenium-cucumber (Junit) project from command prompt.

I tried using the statement in command prompt:

`java -cp E:\Workspace2\AP\Jars\*;E:\Workspace2\AP\src\stepDefinition\ cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue E:\Workspace2\AP\src\cucumberTest\ E:\Workspace2\AP\Feature\LogIn_Test.feature`

but it is showing me following output: [image]

And My eclipse folder structure is as follows:

[image]

**LogIn_Test.feature**

[image]

**Test_steps.java file:**

[image]

**TestRunner.java file:**

[image]

I referred this:

> https://dzone.com/articles/running-cucumber-from-the-command-line

but nothing works. My code didin't ran.

Can anyone guide me to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well at last the Issue is been resolved.

All I have did is in eclipse, just renaming the file "TestRunner" to "TestRunnerTest".

Command Line:

`java -cp "E:\Workspace2\AP\Jars\*;E:\Workspace2\AP\bin" cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue stepDefinition E:\Workspace2\AP\Feature\LogIn_Test.feature`

Thanks to Koen Prins answer, Reference here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/vE_85FW0zks

Also one can refer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z8gm4hFsivI

Comment: Well According to the reference link provided "Depending on your JUnit setup, the default is that JUnit will run only those classes which end in *Test.java"

Answer (score 1):

The steps look good so perhaps it is not finding / using the step definition file.

Maybe the part from the instructions about:

"Your feature files can be added to the end of the command line:

```
$ java -cp "/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.5/cucumber-core-1.2.5.jar:/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/gherkin/2.12.2/gherkin-2.12.2.jar:/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.5/cucumber-java-1.2.5.jar:/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.5/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar" cucumber.api.cli.Main Developer/sources/github/cucumber-jvm-extentreport/src/test/resources/cucumber/feature_one.feature
```

This will probably result in the following message:

```
UUUUUU
3 Scenarios (3 undefined)
6 Steps (6 undefined)
0m0.000s
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:
[snip]
```

This means it can’t find the step definitions, hooks, etc that correspond to your feature file.

Let’s add the glue code required for running the tests. In the below example I’ll use my maven projects target directory, which contains my step definitions in the test-classes directory. **You can do that by adding the directory to your classpath, and with the argument --glue com.sitture.definitions**, provide the Java package that contains step definition Java classes.

```
$ java -cp "/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-core/1.2.5/cucumber-core-1.2.5.jar:/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/gherkin/2.12.2/gherkin-2.12.2.jar:/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-java/1.2.5/cucumber-java-1.2.5.jar:/Users/jreijn/.m2/repository/info/cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps/1.0.5/cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar:/Users/jreijn/Developer/sources/github/cucumber-jvm-extentreport/target/test-classes/" cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue com.sitture.definitions Developer/sources/github/cucumber-jvm-extentreport/src/test/resources/cucumber/feature_one.feature
```

The other part that caught my eye was all steps throwing stuff but I don't know java

Comment: --glue is already added in my command line followed by feature file. But still the command line is not fetching the step definition file.

Comment: What about your classpath, did you update that ?

Comment: Yes, tried with that too but did not helped. Do we need to provide Testrunner class anywhere.

Comment: So you added it per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html ?

Comment: Kindly check again my code: `E:\Workspace2\AP> java -cp E:\Workspace2\AP\Jars\*;E:\Workspace2\AP\src\stepDefinition\ cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue E:\Workspace2\AP\bin\stepDefinition\ E:\Workspace2\AP\Feature\LogIn_Test.feature`

Comment: AlsoI have set CLASSPATH environment variable set to point StepDefinition class

Comment: ok you are copying the file to the right place, how can you verify that you've added it to your class path?

Comment: Please could you show us the exact way that you did that?  We're trying to help solve your problem and it is usually a setup or file location or classpath issue so we'll find out what it is.  Usually it's a 'duh' moment imho, not because anything is wrong in the instructions although that's possible too.

Comment: Is the 'bin' directory supposed to be there ?

Comment: "bin" directs to the java compile code i.e. .class file, where as "src" directs to .java file. Tried with both but nothing worked, same output is appearing

Comment: dunno, maybe try https://hjrlive.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/test-post/ or https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/05/29/selenium-create-an-executable-java-test/ or https://shankargarg.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/create-a-cucumber-project-by-integrating-maven-cucumber-selenium-eclipse/

Comment: To verify CLASSPATH, I opened cmd: c:\> echo  %CLASSPATH%. And it showed me the stepDefinition path in its output

Comment: can you paste that output please, maybe 1 character is off or something

Comment: OutPut for "echo %CLASSPATH%": E:\Workspace2\AP\src\stepDefinition\;

Answer (score 1):

The `--glue` should point to the **java package** in which your glue code resides.

Which in your case, based on the above screenshots, should be “--glue stepDefinition”

One other important aspect is that you will need to add the **compiled output** of the stepdefinitions to your classpath, which in you case should be the full path to the ‘bin’ directory, but you should leave the ‘stepDefinition’ part off.

So try with

```
E:\Workspace2\AP>java -cp "E:\Workspace2\AP\Jars\*;E:\Workspace2\AP\bin" cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue stepDefinition E:\Workspace2\AP\Feature\LogIn_Test.feature
```

Note the quotes around the classpath values.

Comment: This code is giving me: `Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main`

Comment: What if you try this without the quotes? I'm not sure if this is needed on windows and be sure to check out that they are regular quotes. I've modified my post, since it seems my phone added non default quotes.

Comment: Without quotes it will show the output which is mentioned in the question but with quotes it will display `Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main`